# Recursive and no-recursive get different answer

Tags: c, recursion

Sorry that my first language is not English.

The homework is about calculate modulus. The dividend is so big(a^y, a and y may be 10^18) so that I should use the Formula: (m * n)%d=(m%d * n%d)%d to finish that.

So my logic is below:

if y=0, return 1%d

if y=1, return a%d

if y is even, return recursive and let m=n=a^(y/2)

if y is  odd, return recursive and let m=x^(y-1) n=a

the problem is: for y is odd, there is two different way to solve the x:

- 1: calculate it directly (a%d)
- 2: use recursive and the power is 1

You can see my code in below. In the ~~  ~~, if fill in "a%d" is correct but "remain(1)" is wrong.

But only method 1 the answer is correct.

In also using method 1 also can get the correct answer. I still want to know why using method 2 is wrong?
So how to solve the problem by using method 2? If can, how should I modify the code? I cannot, why?

I have been tried to print the sub-answer in any recursive with 2 different methods. I see that method 2 while y is odd its sub-answer is wrong, it may return a negative value.

This is my code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long int a,i,d;

int remain(long long int y){
  if(y==0) return 1%d;
  else if(y==1) return a%d;
  else if(y%2==0) {long long int temp=remain(y/2); return (temp*temp)%d;}
  else if(y%2==1) return ((remain(y-1))*(~~remain(1)~~))%d;
 }

int main(void){
  scanf("%lld %lld %lld",&a,&i,&d);
  printf("%lld\n",remain(i));
  return 0;
}
```

if input 16777215 16777215 23842982

Method 1 answer is 6647725(correct).

Method 2 answer is 12467225(wrong).

TA and I don' t know why method 2 is wrong. My TA suggests me ask this question in here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For low numbers does it work?

Comment: When an `if` contains a `return`, `else` is not needed, and just clutters the code.

Comment: Something I type it wrong. Please replace "x" to "a" in paragraph 8 and 9.

Comment: You should indent your code, and use some spaces in it.  A good guide on how to do that: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html

Comment: Yes, low numbers also work using method 2.

Comment: you can edit it yourself, I think. paragraph[8]? Paragraphs start at 0, or 1? :)

Comment: I have been indent my code when I am coding. But stackoverflow cannot show that(Or I weak to set the format.)

Comment: @childlao don't indent with tabs but with spaces.

Comment: Please don't obfuscate your code like that. Use newlines, spaces, empty lines and comments to make your code more readable. Readable code is easier to understand, and code that is easier to understand will make it easier to maintain. Good habits are also very welcome if you ever want to work with others. And don't use global variables, if you need to pass values to functions, pass them as arguments.

Comment: @childlao Then I'm guessing you are overflowing the type you use. Maybe `int64_t remain(int64_t y);` will work.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I indent with tabs, and SO also recognizes it. You just need to add an extra tab, which is consumed as the code delimiter. So, if you have your indented code with tabs, tabulate everything one more tab, and just copy and paste into SO.  This is worth a self Q&A if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @Jabberwocky You can indent with tabs: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384704/6872717

Answer (score 4):

`remain()` must be defined as `long long int`. 
The way you have it you multiply two `int`s here and observe an integer overflow:

```
else if(y%2==1) return ((remain(y-1))*(remain(1)))%d;
```

I have checked: as soon as I had fixed the definition to

```
long long int remain(long long int y)
```

I got the expected result

Btw. you could have seen this with compiler warnings enabled, because the `printf()` would cause a compiler warning (at least gcc does)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The professor does not focus too much in function type. I don't know the function can also use lld!

Comment: great. if the answer was helful you might want to accept it

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are overflowing the type you use. Maybe `int64_t remain(int64_t y);` will work.

I will use a wider type and fix the style of your code so that you see how to code properly.  I will also make use of fixed-width integers, which are what you should be using 99% of the time (unless a good reason not to is present).

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int64_t a, i, d;


int64_t remain(int64_t y)
{
        int64_t temp;

        if (!y)
                return 1 % d;
        if (y == 1)
                return a % d;
        if (!(y % 2)) {
                temp = remain(y / 2);
                return (temp * temp) % d;
        }
        return (remain(y - 1) * remain(1)) % d;
}


int main(void)
{

        scanf("%"SNCi64" %"SCNi64" %"SCNi64"", &a, &i, &d);
        printf("%"PRIi64"\n", remain(i));

        return 0;
}
```

I didn't fix things such as using global variables, but you should.